# How to authenticate google user using node.js

Tags: node.js

I am using `node.js` for my application and I have to do user authentication via google. I have seen `passport-google` module but I did not get any idea from that and there is no variable for username and password.

One thing is that My application is desktop application .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either do it through OAuth or OpenID for both cases there are very detail examples on passport.js what else you need

for OAuth Example
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth/blob/master/examples/oauth2/app.js

for OpenID Example (deprecated)
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google/blob/master/examples/signon/app.js

I think they are quite self explantory..

Comment: OAuth example seems to have moved here:https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth

Answer (score 2):

`googleapis` module supports OAuth 2.0, there is a an example on https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/examples/oauth2.js